# What does each property in Device Manager Details page mean?

Tags: windows, wmi, device-manager

For every device in the device manager, there are scores of properties listed (see the following image, some of the properties are also highlighted in green). I am unable to find any source which details the meaning of each property. In absence of such a resource one could only guess the meaning from the names.

[image: Device Manager Details]

I am trying to get status of each device programatically to get a list of devices which have been explicitly disabled (from device manages, or otherwise), and some details about them. This lead me to exploring the details page of device manager.

To answer the question you could do either of the following.

1. Refer a link, which explains the meaning of some of the properties.
2. Describe some of the properties which you yourself know.

In either case, I will be creating a list compiled from all answers here, which would have property name, along with its description.

Answer (score 1):

(partial) documentation for Windows 2000 and later:

- [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx)

newer documentation

- [Device Property Reference > System-Defined Device Properties > Device Instance Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541334(v=vs.85).aspx)

For example, you circled the "Status" property, which is defined as follows:

> The `DEVPKEY_Device_DevNodeStatus` device property represents the status of a device node (devnode).
>
> ```
> Property key                      DEVPKEY_Device_DevNodeStatus
> Property-data-type identifier     DEVPROP_TYPE_INT32
> Property access                   Read-only access by installation applications and installers
> Localized?                        No
> ```
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The value of `DEVPKEY_Device_DevNodeStatus` is a bitwise OR of the `DN_` *`Xxx`* bit flags that are defined in Cfg.h

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542414(v=vs.85).aspx